# TorchText doesn't replace unseen words as UNKNOWN in test set

Tags: torch, torchvision, torchtext

Why torch text build vocabulary from train & validation dataset, but when try to prepare test data, the non-seen words should have been assigned as UNKNOWN. But the API throws KeyError for the word. The TorchText TabularDataset and BucketIterator are supposed to convert the unseen words into UNKNOWN words. Anyone faced this issue ?